# Unable to use scss classes directly in next js

Tags: sass, next.js

I have this Layout.module.scss file in next js

```
.app {
  display: flex;
}
```

and in index.js file

when I am including the scss like this it is not working

```
import "./Layout.module.scss";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but when I include scss like this it is working

```
import styles from "./Layout.module.scss";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to use the scss like the first one only, please let me know how I can do that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** install sass dependency using npm:

```
npm install sass --save-dev
```

**Then** rename your file `Layout.module.scss` to `Layout.scss`

And use it like this :

```
import "./Layout.scss";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: So I cannot use module files like that, is there any way to use module files without using the css as object in className?

Comment: No you can't. If you use SCSS as a CSS module, you must use them as how you would use a JS module.